# Display a message with Sweet alert at the beginning of the script

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to display the message `"successfully deleting data"` with Sweet alert, and the beginning of the script:

```
<a href="delete.php?&id=<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" class="delete-link">Delete</a>
```

javascript :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.delete-link').on('click', function() {
        var getLink = $(this).attr('href');
        swal({
            title: 'Alert',
            text: 'Delete?',
            html: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#d9534f',
            showCancelButton: true,
        }, function() {
            window.location.href = getLink
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The data has been successfully deleted, but the way i want to display the data message has been deleted like this, where is it put in?

```
swal("Success!", "Successfully Deleted Data!", "success");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about Sweetalert but as far as I guess the 2nd parameter of the swal function is confirm action!!

So you can delete this using jquery ajax after confirming true:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.delete-link').on('click', function() {
        var getLink = $(this).attr('href');
        swal({
            title: 'Alert',
            text: 'Delete?',
            html: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#d9534f',
            showCancelButton: true,
        }, function() {
            // window.location.href = getLink // no redirection or page reload
            $.ajax({
                url: getLink, // link where your href is
                success: function(result) {
                    swal('Successful!!', 'Successfully deleted!!');  //sweet alert
                }
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for giving comments, I have used javascript, but the success sweetalert notification still doesn't appear.